# Everybody knows that [...] VS Everyone knows that [...]

Tags: writing-style, one-body

I was wondering if we should use one expression rather than the other?

For example the sentence could be:

> Everybody knows that global warming is an important problem

Or

> Everyone knows that global warming is an important problem

Which is better? Which is mostly used for reports?

Comment: This is Off Topic or General Reference for ELU. It might have a home on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: *Everybody knows that the boat is leaking / everybody knows that the captain lied ...*

Comment: The phrasing "Everybody/one knows that..." is extremely unusual for a report. It is chatty, informal, and presumptuous.

Comment: @KitFox At least *everyone* isn't. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everybody%2C+everyone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say, go with the tide:

[image]

([Google nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everybody,everyone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=))
Post-c1931, *everybody* is a loser, *everyone* gains.

Comment: Eh? I think they're both widely enough in use today that it shouldn't matter which OP chooses to use, especially given that they are perfectly interchangeable.

Comment: @KaiserOctavius  "widely enough in use today" is what the nGrams disprove, right?

Comment: No, the nGrams only prove that "everyone" is more widely in use than "everybody" - not that "everybody" is not widely enough in use.

Answer (score 2):

*Everybody* or *everyone* would normally have the third person for subject-verb agreement. So *everybody* or *everyone* **knows** is correct.

As for the choice between *everybody* and *everyone*, that's a matter of [taste](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/everyone):-

> usage: Everyone  and everybody  are
>   interchangeable, as are no one  and nobody,  and someone  and
>   somebody.  Care should be taken to distinguish between everyone  and
>   someone  as single words and every one  and some one  as two words,
>   the latter form correctly being used to refer to each individual
>   person or thing in a particular group: every one of them is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any situation in which the following is a correct usage of grammar

> Everyone know that ...

It would have to be

> Everyone knows that ...

That said, everybody and everyone are mostly interchangeable